# Asp.Net App published to Azure only shows "Your App Service app has been created"

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, publish

I've created an Asp.Net app in Visual Studio and published it to Azure.  Everything seeing to go fine, but instead of seeing my app when I browse to the URL, I see this page:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the VS output log?

Comment: Also you can go to <appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net and check the files under sites folder to verify if all the files are there.

Comment: As mentioned by Brando, ensure that the default document is added. You can also start with the GitHub page - Deployment vs runtime issues : https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues

Answer (score 2):

For me removing the publishing slot was an option. I did that and re-created it again, just starting over from scratch did the trick of re-uploading all the files.

Then: **don't forget to flush the browser cache, or you are looking at the default page while it has actually been published correctly**

Comment: "don't forget to flush the browser cache, or you are looking at the default page while it has actually been published correctly"...This is really a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this page is azure IIS start up page.

I guess you may not set the Default documents(Start page) in the Application settings.

More details about how to set it, you could refer to below image:

The hostingstart.html is the azure web app Default documents page, you see in your browser.

[image]

Also as vijayrkn says, you could use azure kudu console to check you have already publish all the web application to azure successfully.

About how to check it, you could refer to below image:

Locate Advanced Tools and click GO.

[image]

Click Debug console and click site, locate site\wwwroot folder.

[image]

Comment: Application Settings -> Default Documents does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Little late but I just had the same problem. Visual Studio first create a profile for that deployment, after this process it says that publishing is done, but it is not, just the profile creation and App Service instance are done.

To solve this you need to run the publishing again to upload all the files. It helps to run the Preview first and see that all files will be as "Add" instead of "Update", which means that the files are not there yet.

Also there's an option "Publish immediately" instead of "Create Profile" which skips the previous step.

Hope this helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So after going into the **Application Settings** in Azure Portal

set **Default documents** (As the default page you want to load) eg:

> index.aspx

Then set **Virtual applications and directories** (As the default path of your homepage)

**Virtual Path**

> /index.aspx

P.S. Dont mess with the physical path if you dont have to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the files are not in a separate folder, but directly located in the project itself. [image]

Answer (score 0):

In Case Of Java :

1) Copy either the WAR or the WAR EXPLODED FOLDER CREATED BY TOMCAT ON YOUR LOCAL
2) Place the folder under wwwroot > webapps  just the way you treat your file in tomcat on your local
3) Append your Website APP NAME to azure website eg : 
https://azurewebsites.net/
4) You should be able to view your working application

If the step above doesnt work
1) Create a back up of ROOT of FTP azure
2) Copy the application WEB_INF , META-INF and the landing page under ROOT 
access the site !!! 
If everything is working fine give your self a pat on the back .